# How do I retrieve data from database using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is what I did. I am using MVC codeigniter.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: $("#attendance-pick").serialize(),
        url: 'manageLogbook_controller/date_checker/'+ <?php echo $userid; ?>,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            debugger;
            $("#your_attendance").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

and the result should be from.

CONTROLLER

```
function date_checker($userid){
    How can i pass the result to success: function(result) on my View--->
    $result['my_attendance'] = $this->ManageLogbook_model->retrieve_attendance($result); 
}
```

MODEL

```
function retrieve_attendance($userid){
    return  $this->db->where('userid', $userid)
    ->get('attendance')
    ->result();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

controller function:

```
$result['my_attendance'] = $this->ManageLogbook_model->retrieve_attendance($result); 

echo json_encode($result);
```

Ajax function:

```
success: function(response)
{
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
}
```

and don't forget to change the ajax url parameter:

```
url: <?php echo base_url().'manageLogbook_controller/date_checker/'.$userid ?>,
```

Comment: should i do these sir? $("#your_attendance").html(response);

Comment: Yes, n I am not sir :P

Comment: not working, 
success: function(result) {
            var data = JSON.parse(result);
            $("#your_attendance").html(data);
          }

i was thinking about php for each 
from (my_attendance) on CONTROLLER $result['my_attendance'] = $this->ManageLogbook_model->retrieve_attendance($result);

Comment: can you please check what you get in response variable, using console.log?

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: $("#attendance-pick").serialize(),
        url: "<?php echo base_url('manageLogbook_controller/date_checker/'.$userid); ?>",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            $("#your_attendance").html(result.my_attendance);
        }
    });
});
```

your controller

```
function date_checker($userid){
    $my_attendance = $this->ManageLogbook_model->retrieve_attendance($userid); 
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode(array('my_attendance' => $my_attendance));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try the below one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          data: $("#attendance-pick").serialize(),
          url: 'manageLogbook_controller/date_checker/'+ <?php echo $userid; ?>,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(result) {
          console.log(result)
            //$("#your_attendance").html(result);
          }
        });
    });
```

controller

```
function date_checker($userid){
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);

$value = $this->ManageLogbook_model->retrieve_attendance($id);

echo json_encode($value);
```

Model

```
return  $this->db->where('userid', $userid)
    ->get('attendance')
    ->result();
```

I have used console.log in the success part so as to know which data are retrieved so as it can be used as we needed. Please let me know if there is an error. So I can improve my answer.

Comment: Why are you using `$this->uri->segment(3)`? as `date_checker($userid)`  ci is doing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Ajax function in your view :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'user_id':$("#attendance-pick").val()},
    url: '<?php echo site_url("manageLogbook_controller/date_checker"); ?>',
    success: function(result) {
        $("#your_attendance").html(result);
    }
});
```

Controller :

```
function date_checker(){
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $attendance = '';
    $res = $this->ManageLogbook_model->retrieve_attendance($user_id);
    foreach($res as $r){
        $attendance = $r->attendance;
    }
    echo $attendance;
}
```

Model :

```
function retrieve_attendance($userid){
    $this->db->select('attendance');
    $this->db->from('your_table_name');
    $this->db->where('user_id',$userid);
    $res = $this->db->get();
    return $res->result();
}
```

Hope this helped..
Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: $("#attendance-pick").serialize(),
        url: 'manageLogbook_controller/date_checker/ ?>,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
          $("#your_attendance").html(result);
        }
   });
});

//Controller


function date_checker($userid){
  $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
  $value = $this->ManageLogbook_model->retrieve_attendance($user_id);
  echo json_encode($value);
}

After this you can parse the json in the success of ajax and display it in the view
```